# Authentication Error Connecting to TFS through Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, restful-authentication

I know little to none about Rest API calls so bear with me. I am trying to queue a TFS 2017 build using Rest API through Powershell. I tried using the TFS API but found out that will not be able to work for me. This is what I have:

```
$Uri = "http://MyTFS:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.0"
$TFSAPIKeyForAutomatedBuild = SecretKey
$body = @"
   {
    "definition": 
        {
         "ID": "BuildID"
        },
    "RequestedFor":
        {
        "Id":"MyID"
        }
    }
"@
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $TFSAPIKeyForAutomatedBuild")
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -header $headers -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $Body)
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client
>   authentication required

As an aside, I have already been able to queue a build using Postman so it should work one way or another.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use the "credential" parameter?

Comment: Yes I have tried the credential parameter and I get the same error

Comment: Can you try the following: $User = "username";$Password = "password";$securePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $securePassword);$releaseresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Credential $credential -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri; ?

Comment: Yes that is the exact code that I used. Still the same error :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what fixed my issue. You have to encode the Token used to connect to TFS like so:

```
$encodedPAT = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$TFSAPIKeyForAutomatedBuild"))
$Uri = "http://MyTfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Projects/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.0"

$body = @{ definition = @{id = BuildID} }
$bodyJson = ConvertTo-Json $body

write-host $bodyJson
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $encodedPAT")

$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -header $headers -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)
```

I also changed the format of my json because it was throwing an error regarding deserialization.